Solana - raydium swap functionality
I want to use Raydium swap functionality, but I don't know, how to get the full data for instructions. So far, I can receive these vars by listening to the events of liquidity pools (but I cannot get the serum vars).
I'm using  this method to get the accounts and parse them.
  const accounts = tx?.transaction.message.instructions.find(
    (ix) => ix.programId.toBase58() === RAYDIUM_PUBLIC_KEY
  ).accounts;


 
    TokenProgram
    AmmId
    AmmAuthority
    AmmOpenOrders
    AmmTargetOrders
    PoolCoinTokenAccount
    PoolPcTokenAccount
    SerumProgramId
    SerumMarket
    SerumBids ---- cannot get
    SerumAsks ---- cannot get
    SerumEventQueue ---- cannot get
    SerumCoinVaultAccount ---- cannot get
    SerumPcVaultAccount ---- cannot get
    SerumVaultSigner ----- cannot get


How can I get Serum vars here?
